# Mysql union help

Tags: mysql, union

Hi I have a query like that

> SELECT column1,MAX(column2) AS MAX FROM
>   table1 GROUP BY column1 ORDER BY MAX
>   DESC;

and i have a second table which name table2 and has same column2 but different column1 name,
I want to apply this query to union of these table,when i try this

> SELECT column1,MAX(column2) AS MAX FROM
>   ((SELECT * FROM table1) union (SELECT
>   * FROM table2)) GROUP BY column1 ORDER BY MAX DESC;

I got this error "ERROR 1248 (42000): Every derived table must have its own alias"

how can i do that? thanks for help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The alias comes after the derived table definition,

```
SELECT column1,MAX(column2) AS MAX FROM 
(SELECT * FROM table1 union SELECT * FROM table2) t3 
GROUP BY column1 ORDER BY MAX DESC;
```

The alias is `t3`